# Where do I get website screen shots to show responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design

I am preparing a website manual for my client. My website is responsive and working fine. However, in my manual I want to include screen shots.

Where do I get online tool that will render me a snapshot containing at least 3 devices showing website responsiveness? I am talking of something like this:

[image: something like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question requirement, your best matching solution is  [here](http://ami.responsivedesign.is)

you can view my example. This what i created for my website [image: here]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one helped me....

Comment: you are very much welcome

Answer (score 0):

It's included in the developer tools of Chrome (Ctrl+shift+J => little "phone" on the top left or Ctrl+shift+M in the developer tools).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can generate screenshots on different screen sizes using a cross-browser testing tool. The one that would serve your need the best is https://www.browserstack.com/responsive

However, it won't create them in the layout example you provided. You'd need to do that manually in Photoshop or whichever design software you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

All three devices have a means to capture screenshots. You would capture the screenshots on the devices and send them to a computer where you could use any basic picture editing program like Paint or GIMP to overlay them on each other.

If you want the devices themselves to be visible as in the picture, you'd take the pictures with a digital camera and use Paint or GIMP etc.